# Экранирование строки в PHP

Tags: php

Занялся изучением PDO и перехожу на него с MySQLi. В одном месте кода мне приходится экранировать символы в строке для того, чтобы потом использовать их в БД (MySQLi::real_escape_string()), но мне не нужно отбивать ее кавычками (так делает PDO::quote()). Можно ли использовать addslashes() как альтернативу?

Comment: @cheremushkin забудьте про стоковые функции php с обработкой запросов, PDO сделает "грязную" работу за вас, если вы правильно всё приготовите. Ответ @Construct считаю полностью исчерпывающим вопрос.

Comment: @Construct, перевидите свой комментарий в ответ и я его отмечу как лучший.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А может лучше использовать `prepared statements`?